# PHP : Detect Remote Dekstop Access

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create web applications based on PHP CodeIgniter. I make this web application running through the LAN access, but I have a problem when someone accesses the website through a computer in a LAN network using remote access such as TeamViewer. I want to make this website can only be accessed without using remote access. I want to detect the presence of TeamViewer or access remotely when users access my website. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the php code on each of the clients that connects, or is there a server running the php code? If you aren't running the web application on each client you will  have to use java or write an progam that are ran on each client, to check for remote access programs.

Comment: i running the PHP code on each of the client that connects. do you have an idea to make the code in PHP ?

Comment: Well the easiest way to do it if you wanna do it in PHP, is to execute `pgrep`command for Linux, `tasklist`for Windows, I am not sure what's that command is called in Mac though. 
My thoughts was, that what you would do is run these commands and look for TeamViewer (and other remote access apps) and if they are on the tasklist, then they are running. 

What platforms are you going to run it on?

Comment: I use Windows platform. I have no idea to code. Perhaps we can see the TeamViewer active in the tasklist. But I do not know if someone is doing remote access to the computer. This is because TeamViewer is usually always active at startup where computer users are not necessarily used. In this case, I just wanted to know if the computer is being accessed remotely.

Comment: Well the easy way would just be to not make it able to run if TeamViewer is open, but if you wanna be able to detect if TeamViewer has a connection running, then you prob. Need to look at the network interface at find out what packages belongs to TeamViewer.  But this is a lot of work, the best solution would be to just force the user to close TeamViewer